# WPF TreeView : How to create header and nodes from different models

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am working on a wpf project where I have to build tree nodes recursively. What I wanted to do is assign header for the nodes from another model for example:

```
    Request Header  --> node1
                -->node1.1
                -->node1.2
    Response Header  -->node2 
                -->node2.1
                -->node2.2

// building tree 
   public List<TreeModel> BuildTree(IEnumerable<string> strings)
      {
        return (
          from s in strings
          let split = s.Split('.')
          group s by s.Split('.')[0] into g
          select new TreeModel
          {
              Value = g.Key,
              Children = BuildTree(
                from s in g
                where s.Length > g.Key.Length + 1
                select s.Substring(g.Key.Length + 1))
          }
          ).ToList();


    }

 // Here I am creating static MessageElementModel  objects
```

The reason why I am creating these objects is I want to associate them to another       control(combobox) to create on select event but this is not  part of my question.

```
      public List<MessageElementModel> GetAllMessageElements()
       {
        string[] request = { "NetworkControl.AlternateIndexText.Value" };
        string[] request2 = { "NetworkControl.NetworkControl.AddressData.TransactionOriginatorID.Value" };
        string[] request3 = { "VehicleSummary.VehicleIdentification.IdentificationID.Value" };

       transactionTypeWSRequestXmlType = TransactionTypeModle.TransactionTypeWSRequestXmlType;
        transactionTypeWSResponseXmlType = TransactionTypeModel.TransactionTypeWSRequestXmlType;


        messageElements.Add(new MessageElementModel(1, transactionTypeWSRequestXmlType,transactionTypeWSResponseXmlType, TreeNode.BuildTree(request)));
        messageElements.Add(new MessageElementModel(1, transactionTypeWSRequestXmlType,transactionTypeWSResponseXmlType, TreeNode.BuildTree(request2)));


        return messageElements;

    }

    The transactionTypeWSRequestXmlType,transactionTypeWSResponseXmlType and transactionTypeWSRequestXmlType,transactionTypeWSResponseXmlType are the headers of the tree (TreeNode.BuildTree(request))
```

In the XAML I have

```
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}" Content="{Binding Value}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>

        </TreeView>



    How can I add header from another model? for this case transactionTypeWSRequestXmlType,transactionTypeWSResponseXmlType and transactionTypeWSRequestXmlType,transactionTypeWSResponseXmlType to the treeview for the nodes I am creating in the TreeNode.BuildTree(request) recursively? 


             and the same for var response;
        var treeNode = new ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel>() { request,   response };
        }
        return treeNode;
       }
 In the messageElementViewModel I am getting the constructed      nods(TreeNodeModel)+roots(TransactionTypeViewModel)

 here I addded Id so that when I chose any transaction from my Transaction combobox the    tree will display only matching Ids

   public List<MessageElementViewModel> GetAllTreeNodesList()
    {
        messageElements = TransactionType.getAllTreeNodes().Select(msgElements => new      MessageElementViewModel
        {
            Id = msgElements.Id,
            Request = msgElements.Request,
            Response = msgElements.Response,

        }).ToList();

        return messageElements;
    }       
//make it observable 

  public ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel> GetAllTreeNodes()
    {
        observableMessageElement = new ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel>  (messageElements);
        return observableMessageElement;

    }

 //xaml binding to MessageElementViewModel where I have the roots and nodes combination

  How can I bind all these together in the xaml?
```

Comment: Create a single ViewModel to which the View Binds to, then use this ViewModel to "wrap" the models.

Comment: HighCore Can you please give me more detail? maybe a code example

Comment: If you want to differentiate different types of nodes, the easiest way to do it is provide distinct types for each type of node, and then create different data templates for each of these node types.

Comment: Will what do yo mean by distinct types. are you referring to the request and response roots I am talking about?can I see it in a code sample?

Comment: I found a way to resolve this i will post solution shortly